# How to make fixed elements hide on scroll and then appear when the user is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I have a hidden element that gets `display: block;` when the user has scrolled a certain amount of pixels and hides when the user has reached a certain point of the page. This works fine on desktop computers and laptops. But the problem is tablets. I have a iPad 2 and a Samsung Galaxy Tab4. That fixed element causes the scrolling on both tablets to be laggy. I have made a JavaScript function that hides the element when you are scrolling and shows it again when you are not scrolling. It works, but is really slow. When you start scrolling it hides the element when you release your finger from the screen. It just doesn't work quite that well.

Here is the code:

```
function hideElementsOnScroll() {
    var body = $("body");

    if(body.hasClass("ipad") || body.hasClass("tablet-chrome")) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var offsetTop = $("#sd-tabs").offset().top;

            if(windowTop >= offsetTop && $(".scroll-tabs").hasClass("stickyTabs")) {
                $(window).scroll($.debounce( 0, true, function() {
                    $(".scroll-tabs").css("visibility", "hidden");
                }));
                $(window).scroll($.debounce( 100, function() {
                    $(".scroll-tabs").css("visibility", "visible");
                }));
            } else {
                if(windowTop < offsetTop) {
                    $(".scroll-tabs").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    $(window).scroll($.debounce( 1, true, function() {
                        $(".scroll-tabs").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    }));
                    $(window).scroll($.debounce( 1, function() {
                        $(".scroll-tabs").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a plugin that does this? Or do I need to edit my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the answer from @RiZKiT I was able to fix my problem. I combined the on("touchstart") and on("touchend") with the debounce and made this function:

```
function hideElementsOnScroll() {
    var body = $("body");
    if(body.hasClass("ipad") || body.hasClass("tablet-chrome")) {
        $(window).on("touchstart", function() {
            $(".scrollable").css("visibility", "hidden");
        });
        $(window).on("touchend", function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                $(window).scroll($.debounce( 1, true, function() {
                    $(".scrollable").css("visibility", "hidden");
                }));
                $(window).scroll($.debounce( 1, function() {
                    $(".scrollable").css("visibility", "visible");
                }));
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can use this function in their project

Comment: First of all, good that my info was helpful for you. BUT, your solution creates a lot of events on every touchstart, they count up to thousands very fast! Try it to add `console.log('show')` below your `$(".scrollable").css("visibility", "visible");`. Thats why I improved my answer with an example how it could be done more elegant. Feel free to ask if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile devices the scroll events are often delayed until scroll end, to improve the performance of the browser and the events are all executed at once then. That's not what you want.

Checking the position while scrolling, will always be laggy at the current standard of mobile devices. So I suggest to drop the idea of hiding an element after a certain amount of pixels, on mobile devices.

Instead, try to use a combination of on("touchstart") or one("touchmove") and scroll debounce, something like that:

```js
function hideOnScroll(selector, container){
    var $container = $(container || window),
     $elements = $(selector, $container),
     showElement = $.debounce(500, function() {
            $elements.css("visibility", "visible");
        });
    $container.on("touchstart", function() {
        $container.off("scroll", showElement);
        $elements.css("visibility", "hidden");
        $container.one("touchend", function() {
            $container.on("scroll", showElement);
        });
    });
}
hideOnScroll('nav', '.container');
```

```css
html, body { 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container { 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
article {
    height: 10000px;
}
nav { 
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black; 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <nav></nav>
    <article class="content"></article>
</div>

<!-- jquery & debounce -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>(function(b,c){var $=b.jQuery||b.Cowboy||(b.Cowboy={}),a;$.throttle=a=function(e,f,j,i){var h,d=0;if(typeof f!=="boolean"){i=j;j=f;f=c}function g(){var o=this,m=+new Date()-d,n=arguments;function l(){d=+new Date();j.apply(o,n)}function k(){h=c}if(i&&!h){l()}h&&clearTimeout(h);if(i===c&&m>e){l()}else{if(f!==true){h=setTimeout(i?k:l,i===c?e-m:e)}}}if($.guid){g.guid=j.guid=j.guid||$.guid++}return g};$.debounce=function(d,e,f){return f===c?a(d,e,false):a(d,f,e!==false)}})(this);</script>
```